# Bumpers and p2os

Tags: ros, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have discovered that p2os does not provide bumpers access, is there any way to do it by myself?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143076/bumpers-and-p2os/) by [NullX4](https://answers.ros.org/users/11546/nullx4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-03-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rosaria](http://wiki.ros.org/rosaria) publishes bumper data if you want to use that instead.

Or, if you want to implement bumpers in p2os_driver you could do it similar to the existing sonar, gripper, etc data.   See the robot manual for details on the Pioneer communications protocol.   If you do it, send a pull request (request to merge) to [allenh's git repository](https://github.com/allenh1/p2os) so that they can include your additions.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1